# Get containing generic types with ClassTag

Tags: java, scala, reflection, types, guava

I know that guava's TypeToken is capable of this:

```
class C[I, O]    

class A[T] {
  val tok = new TypeToken[T](getClass){}
}

val a = new A[C[Integer, String]]{}
println(a.tok)  // somepackage.C<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.String>
```

But with scala's ClassTag, I get:

```
class B[T: ClassTag] {
  // runtime class
  val clazz = implicitly[ClassTag[T]].runtimeClass
  // also tries to construct a guava type token
  val tok = TypeToken.of(clazz).asInstanceOf[TypeToken[T]]
}

val b = new B[C[Integer, String]]
println(b.clazz)  // class somepackage.C
println(b.tok)    // somepackage.C
```

So with ClassTag, the genetic types contained by C are lost. Is it possible to get somepackage.C with ClassTag or other things in scala?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeToken` does an interesting trick. Let's say you have this:

```
class A[T]
class B extends A[String]
```

Though Java erases type parameters at runtime, the superclass of `B` is not `A[T]`, but `A[String]`. That information is preserved, and can be obtained. So when you do this:

```
val tok = new TypeToken[T](getClass){}
```

The `{}` at the end means you are creating an *anonymous subclass* of `TypeToken`, one which is nested on `A[T]`, so that each instance of `A[T]` will actually result in a different anonymous subclass.

Anyway, that's the basic idea, and it depends on anonymous subclasses nested inside the parameterized class. Just having a `ClassTag` (which is mostly a wrapper around `Class`) isn't good enough.

Scala *can* preserve the full type information using `TypeTag`, but that comes with a cost. Scala's type system is rather complex, much more complex than Java's, and, because of that, preserving the full type information requires a lot of code.

So, whereas `ClassTag`, which mostly depends on Java's bundled `Class`, comes with `scala-library`, to use `TypeTag` you need to add `scala-reflect` to your dependencies, which is around 4.2MB on Scala 2.11.4.

Once you have that, however, the rest is trivial, as shown by [lmm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1135948/lmm) (shameless copy&paste from his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27804582/53013)):

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class C[I, O]

class A[T: TypeTag] {
  val tpe = typeOf[T]
}

val a = new A[C[Integer, String]]
println(a.tpe) // C[java.lang.Integer,String]
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But can we construct a java.lang.reflect.Type from TypeTag ?

Comment: @darkjh I don't think so.

Answer (score 3):

I think you want `TypeTag` and `typeOf`

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class C[I, O]

class A[T: TypeTag] {
  val tpe = typeOf[T]
}

val a = new A[C[Integer, String]]
println(a.tpe) // C[java.lang.Integer,String]
```